# jQuery- smooth scrolling a parallax page to certain anchors by mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I'm working on a parallax page using Stellar.js, I have some parallax panes stacked to each other like this:

[image: when user scroll down to the second pane, it must scroll automatic to reach the top of page]

I want a smooth scroll-to-top for each pane when user scroll down the page and reached that  pane.
I mean I want the scroller be smart enough to align each pane to the top of screen.
I tried this but didn't work:

```
h = $(window).height();
t = $('#parallaxtop').offset().top + $('#parallaxtop').height();
if(t > h) {
    $(window).scrollTop(t - h);
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LDaUw/

Comment: If you can provide a working, illustrative JSFiddle, that would be great!

Comment: I've just add the JSFiddle page link.

Comment: Why don't you use another plugin for that such as [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this working:

```
var pageH = $(window).innerHeight(); //grab window height
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
            var eTop = $('#parallaxtop').offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
            var myOffset = eTop - $(window).scrollTop(); //determine the offset from window
            if (myOffset > -100 && myOffset < pageH/2) { //if the offset is less than the half of page scroll to the panel
                    $('#parallaxtop').ScrollTo({ //ScrollTo JQuery plugin
                    });
            }
        }, 250)); //this will be calculated 250ms after finishing every scroll
    });
```

I've used the [ScrollTo JQuery plugin](http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/) for smooth scrolling.